# Strange Blank Line on TabbedView + ViewPager

Tags: android

I've done a tabbedView that hold a ListView in a fragment and i used an ActionToolbar on which I have disabled sliding

Now i see that my ListView is covered by a Blank Space that i do not even know how to name

How to delete it?

XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/slider_tab"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

OnCreateMethod of the Activity that contains my fragment

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SliceAppDB.init();
        ActivityManager.TaskDescription taskDescription = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription("SliceApp",null, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        ((Activity)this).setTaskDescription(taskDescription);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.slider_tab));
        AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
        params.setScrollFlags(0);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(vpPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vpPager);
        setupTabIcons();
        TabLayout.Tab tab= tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
        tab.select();


    }
```

[image]